# Symfony2 / JMS Serializer - How to manage differents object structure?

Tags: php, json, symfony, jmsserializerbundle

Here is a simplified version of my doctrine entity/ php class :

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Command{

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $customerName;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=50)
     */
    private $customerNickname;

    // Other fields ...
}
```

With a basic JMS Serialier bundle configuration, i can easily serialize one "Command" object to a JSON like :

```
{
   "id": "1",
   "customerName": "Logan",
   "customerNickname": "Wolverine",
   "..."
}
```

But, in my case, the output JSON format i need is imposed, and i would like to have a sub-object structure like :

```
{
   "id": "1",
   "customer":
   {
       "customerName": "Logan",
       "customerNickname": "Wolverine",
   }
}
```

Because i have a lot of classes in that case, i would prefere not change my class structure (php side)

Except "pre|post-serialize" event (which seems a little heavy to such a thing), i didn't find solution in official JMS Serializer bundle.

What it the easiest solution to do this ?

Best regards

Comment: if you don't want to change your classes, you'll have to use pre/post serialize

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the record, you should probably use pre/post serialize but I found another way around this. Firstly, I enabled the reading of metadata:

```
# app/config/config.yml
jms_serializer:
    metadata:
        auto_detection: true
```

and then created the folder `App\CoreBundle\Resources\config\serializer\` and created the relevant file `yaml` (e.g. `Entity.User.yml`).

Then I exclude everything, and use `virtual_properties` to format the data how I wish.

```
App\CoreBundle\Entity\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        id:
            expose: true
    virtual_properties:
            getCustomer:
                serialized_name: customer
```

I then created a method in my User entity which returned the data I wanted in the correct format. For you, something like:

```
public function getCustomer()
{
    return array(
        'customerName' => $this->getCustomerName(),
        'customerNickname' => $this->getCustomerNickname()
    );
}
```

Comment: As you say, i will finally use post/pre serialize events, because i have to handle deserialization too and virtual property doesn't support it :(. 
But this is still a good anwser for a serialization only purpose :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of serialize your two properties, you can create a virtual one with the [VirtualProperty](http://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#virtualproperty) annotation.

```
/**
 * @Serializer\VirtualProperty
 * @Serializer\SerializedName("customer")
 *
 * @return array
 */
public function getCustomer()
{
    return [
        'customerName' => $this->customerName, 
        'customerNickname' => $this->customerNickname
    ];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Finally, like Prisoner point it out, i will use event to handle deserialization too.